# await / observe within function

Tags: javascript, async-await, observable

I cannot get my head around this. 
How can I wait for i==2 to finish before continuing with the other i's?

```js
class Observable {
    constructor() {
        this.observers = [];
    }
    subscribe(f) {
        this.observers.push(f);
    }
    unsubscribe(f) {
        this.observers = this.observers.filter(subscriber => subscriber !== f);
    }
    notify(data, options) {
        this.observers.forEach(observer => observer(data));
    }
}

let myObserver = new Observable();

for (let i=0; i <= 2; i++){
    let proc = async function processor(foo) {
        console.log('Processing ' + i + ' ' + foo);

        if (i != 2){
            //await for i = 2 to finish
            //??? <----
        }

        // do other stuff which requires i = 2 
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, i * 1000));
        console.log('Done ' + i);
    }

    myObserver.subscribe(proc);
}

myObserver.notify('Hello');
```

I've added a more concrete example - might shed some light what I actually try to accomplish. (The same Observable class as above is used)

```
let allData = {};

let dataProviders = {
    provderA: {
        url: 'http://provder.a.com',
        observer: new Observable(),
        requires: null
    },
    providerB: {
        url: 'http://provder.b.com',
        observer: new Observable(),
        requires: 'providerA'
    }
}

let consumers = {
    consumerX: {
        provider: 'providerA'
    },
    consumerY: {
        provider: 'providerB'
    },
    consumerZ: {
        provider: 'providerB'
    }
}

function getData(providerName) {
    let urlParam = '';

    if (dataProviders[providerName][requires] != null) {
        // (a)wait for providerA / dataProviders[providerName][requires]
        // ??? <----
        urlParam += allData[dataProviders[providerName][requires]]['parameter']
    }

    $.getJSON(dataProviders[providerName][url] + urlParam).done(function (result) {
        allData[providerName] = result;
        dataProviders[providerName][observer].notify(allData)
    });
}

for (const consumer of Object.keys(consumers)) {
    let subscription = function (data) {
        console.log('process data');
        console.log(data)
    }
    dataProviders[consumers[consumer]['provider']].subscribe(subscription);
}

for (const providerName of Object.keys(dataProviders)) {
    getData(providerName);
}
```

Comment: Well what do you intend to do in that for block? Is it asynchronous? What do you mean *"wait for i = 2 to finish"* - literally just an assignment? That's synchronous.

Comment: (Might be a bit too much stripped down.) the foo argument is a rather large dataset and the for block is actually reading from an object containing different sources ($.getJSON(...)). But I have a dependency where I need to wait for certain sources to collect it's data. (= yes it's asynchronous). wait for i = 2 to finish means to wait for those other sources to collect the data.

Comment: And can you not just use await as you've done elsewhere? What's the *problem*?

Comment: Uh, `i` will always only be `0` or `1` in that loop, never `2`.

Comment: I suspect you should not use a loop around `myObserver.subscribe` (subscribing multiple different processors), but rather put the loop inside the `processor` function.

Comment: I've added a more concrete example (2nd code block). To explain my problem better.

Comment: `await for ... of` - ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for

```
async function getData(providerName) {
    const { url, requires } = dataProviders[providerName];
    let urlParam = '';
    if (requires != null) {
        const requiredData = await new Promise(resolve => {
            dataProviders[requires].observer.subscribe(() => {
                resolve(allData[requires]);
            });
            // getData(requires); ???
        });
        urlParam += requiredData.parameter;
    }

    const result = await $.getJSON(url + urlParam);
    allData[providerName] = result;
    dataProviders[providerName][observer].notify(allData);
}
```

You could simplify the subscription of the `resolve`r callback if you did notifiy your observers with the specific `result`, not `allData`. However, I guess you could drop that `Observer` class altogether and just use a promise instead, if you are not fetching the data multiple times. That would allow you to get rid of the `allData` store and just memoise the promise returned by `getData`, simplifying the whole code a lot:

```
const dataProviders = {
    provderA: {
        url: 'http://provder.a.com',
        promise: null,
        requires: null
    },
    providerB: {
        url: 'http://provder.b.com',
        promise: null,
        requires: 'providerA'
    }
};
function getDataOnce(providerName) {
    const provider = dataProviders[providerName];
    if (provider.promise == null)
        provider.promise = getData(provider);
    return provider.promise;
}
async function getData({ url, requires }) {
    let urlParam = '';
    if (requires != null) {
        const requiredData = await getDataOnce(requires);
        urlParam += requiredData.parameter;
    }

    const result = await $.getJSON(url + urlParam);
    return result;
}

const consumers = {
    consumerX: {
        provider: 'providerA'
    },
    consumerY: {
        provider: 'providerB'
    },
    consumerZ: {
        provider: 'providerB'
    }
};    
for (const consumer of Object.values(consumers)) {
    getDataOnce(consumer.provider).then(data =>
        console.log('process data');
        console.log(data)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I need the Observer class because the fetching will be triggered on $(document).ready but later upon user request several times.

adding a resolve to the observer did the trick :-)

Comment: But does that mean that a changing `parameter` response needs to automatically re-trigger the other fetches that `require` it?

Comment: basically yes. The example is still quite simplified. It's for a CPE Monitoring solution and data changes quite often and depend upon each other. Using the observer pattern and (with your help) the required parameter dependency I can now simple trigger one or more dataProviders and all dependencies are fetched and the corresponding UI-elements are being updated.

Also: I learned something from you :-)

Comment: @Simon You might want to have a look at rxjs then, as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a promise here.

```
async function getData(providerName) {

    if (dataFromAnotherProviderIsNeeded) {
        // wait till promise resolve
        await new Promise( async (resolve) => {
            await getData(anotherProvider);
            // when request is done, resolve
            resolve();
        };
    }

    // Previous request is done 

}
```

Another option would be to use concat from rxjs to wait till the first request emit before doing the second request (using rxjs is much more powerful but maybe not needed on a simple case).